# How can a service detect when windows has started completely?

Tags: java, c, windows, networking, service

I'm writing a service and the service uses WMI to get the mac address of the system, problem is if the service starts on boot, it seems that the information I get is different than when I get after the operating system is fully initialized. Hence, how can I detect that the OS is initialized so that I can get the proper mac address?

languages are C and java,
platforms are windows 7 and windows xp

Comment: *"get the mac address of the system"*  Why?

Comment: Define "fully initialized". It should help you find the answer.

Comment: fully initialized as in the MAC address is set properly, right now the mac address on startup is some value and once everything is initialized, the mac address is another value which is the one I want

Comment: I'm also running it in a virtual machine, do normal hosts have the habit of changing the mac address too?

Answer (score 1):

Normal hosts take their MAC address from the hardware which does not change.  There is no specific point at which you can say an OS has started fully, you just have to wait.

I suspect the mac address change is not something the OS will notify you about or is dependant on when the OS starts, its likely that this just happens at about the same time.

Comment: Ok just discovered that it only changes when running on VM, for my host machine, it doesn't change